# Altium Keep-Out Layer Locked

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers, drawing

When I try to draw a line in the Keep-Out Layer in Altium by clicking the tab for the Keep-Out Layer and placing a line, the layer suddenly changes to a different one and prevents me from adding to the Keep-Out Layer. Additionally, when I try to place a line and press the Tab key and try to select the Keep-Out Layer from the Layer dropdown box, it doesn't appear in the list. How can I add shapes to the Keep-Out Layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Altium doesn't allow you to draw standard primitives on the keepout layer. Instead you need to use the Place -> Keepout menu. From within the menu you can select which type of primitive you want to draw on the keepout layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is convert the track/primitive (in my case a drawing imported from .dwg) to keepout, that worked out form me:

Select the objects then go to: Tools>Convert>Convert Selected Primitives to Keepouts

[image: Select the objects then go to: Tools>Convert>Convert Selected Primitives to Keepouts]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're in PCB mode (not board edit mode) by pressing 2 OR View->2D layout mode.
2. Try changing your layers options in view configurations (on mine by pressing L key) OR by changing the 2D viewing mode.

The place to change the board shape is in the [board edit mode](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-BoardShape((Board+Shape))_AD)

Here are instructions on how to properly draw a [keepout layer](http://documentation.circuitstudio.com/display/CSTU/PCB_Obj-Keepout((Keepout))_CS)

One more idea: as a workaround you might be able to make a shape on a different layer and then open up the properties for that shape or line and change it to keepout.

Comment: Hope one of those might help

Comment: All of those are what I am doing. The problem is that when I go to place a shape in the Keepout layer, it does not let me.

Comment: One more idea...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems to work is Place/KeepOut/Track.
Which is interesting because this places a line not a trace.
What used to work was P/L while keepout was selected.